# How to select elements from previous div that have the same position inside parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, match

```
<ul class="user-text">
  <li class="user-text">User 1 Text</li>
  <li class="user-text" style="display:none">User 2 text</li>
  <li class="user-text" style="display:none">User 3 text</li>
  <li class="user-text" style="display:none">User 4 text</li>
</ul>

<ul class="user">
  <li class="user">User 1 image</li>
  <li class="user">user 2 image</li>
  <li class="user">user 3 image</li>
  <li class="user">user 4 image</li>
</ul>
```

I think this works similar to a image slider.
What I want to achieve is : on "User 2 image" : hover -- set "User 2 text" : display visible (hide all other user texts).
The same if I hover on any other "User image". I cannot figure out how to match the position from each div.

All help is welcome. Thank you.

If this is a duplicate, please point to the resolved situation.

Comment: I have tried it but haven't got figured out a solution on my own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('li.user' ).hover(function(){
  $('li.user-text:eq('+$(this).index()+')').show().siblings().hide();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u0300h0d/)**

Comment: no need for callback if you are using hover, it will hide it automatically

Comment: This does exactly what I had in mind. Thank you very much.

Comment: @zanu: glad it helps..:) dont forget to accept the helped answer ..http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".user").hover(function(){
  $(".user-text").index($(this).index()).show();
});
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create structure for your slider something like this:

```
<ul class="user">
            <li class="user">User 1 image
                <div class="user-text">User 1 image text</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Apply *position: relative* to class "user" and use *position: absolute* to set position for class "user-text".

OR try:

```
$('.user').on('mouseover', 'li', function () {
    $('.user-text').eq($(this).index()).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

Comment: I need to show all User images, and the text only for the hovered user : https://jsfiddle.net/fere_tzau/u0300h0d/3/  this does not work. But I would rather use your HTML version Manish. Seems more correct.

Comment: Please have a look on the modified jsfiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/u0300h0d/4/

Result can be achieved only via CSS, without using any JS.

Comment: I need to further add some different action on this and it cannot be done only with CSS.

Comment: Then you can use JavaScript to achieve the desired functionality ;-)